# when start Application than Remove this Titanium Startscreen(create custom Start Screen)

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am Application Developer with the Titanium. i want to develop new Application with Titanium and created a HelloWorld application. Every time my application starts up Than every time  Titanium startscreen is show. how I remove this Titanium Startscreen.

Comment: are you talking about red splash screen of titanium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default titanium splash is screen path is:

> Resources/iphone/Deafult.png

You can replace your new Default.png. To see the new splash screen, just clean your build and relaunch your application.

Comment: I don't about that,
Please, tell me  Step by Step,
how i can do, 
Thanks for Your Response

Comment: Resources directory is in your project folder.