# when start App, than how to remove this Titanium default Page or picture?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am new Application Developer with the Titanium. i want to develop new Application with Titanium and created a HelloWorld application. Every time my application starts up Than every time Titanium startscreen is show. how I remove this Titanium Startscreen.

I have also 1 question when i run the application in iPhone than show its title bar with windows.
but, in android have not show. 
i use build custom with use if else statement i add the title bar. but, any syntax. whose add the tittle bar in android.

Comment: Titanium Android don't have windows title bar.

Comment: Sure, Android have no window Title bar....

Comment: what's the question then? Do you want to remove the splash screen or title bar?

Comment: two question 
1. splash screen remove 
2. Title bar add (where Window name show or add navBut)

Comment: Solution of your first problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206661/when-start-application-than-remove-this-titanium-startscreencreate-custom-start

Comment: Thanks a lots, have u any personal id just a Facebook or another.

Comment: ok, Thanks you, 
i contact you earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also occur this type problem than, i sort out this problem with the help of my friend.
I write below step by step.

1. go to the resource folder where u create ur application.
2. select the build folder and open iphone and copy the picture whose u want to show on screen.
3. and rename with default.png

I, think this is useful to you. Let try it.